# big monstrous reveal intelligently withheld

Tags: meaning-in-context

*The Ritual is an efficient, well-made if programmatic Brit horror, with good effects and a **big monstrous reveal intelligently withheld**.*

Source: https://www.theguardian.com/film/2017/oct/12/the-ritual-review-rafe-spall-brit-horror

I am not sure how to understand the passage in bold. Does it mean that the appearance of the monster is shown not until the end of the movie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "reveal", in film jargon, is when a fact that has been hidden from the audience is shown. It may be a "twist" in the plot, such as when a person that the audience thinks is a "goodie" is revealed to be a "baddie". It may be that the thing that the audience thinks is a monster is revealed to be a robot.

A big reveal, such as "The guy that you think is the hero is actually a villan" has to be hidden from the audience. The audience has to be tricked. So this movie has some kind of secret, but it is cleverly hidden, and you will be surprised when it is revealed. The secret has something to do with the monster, but the writer isn't telling you any more because that would spoil the movie.

Lots of movies have a big reveal. Examples include "The Sixth sense" "The Empire Strikes Back". "The Planet of the Apes", "Psycho". If you know any of these movies you will know how there is a big reveal near the end of all of them.